# Add [name] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Models\Products], если я уже добавил поле name в fillable

Tags: laravel

Как ясно из названия, я добавил это поле, и это должно было решить проблему, но ошибка вылезает каждый раз, когда я по форме пытаюсь добавить товар на сайт, метод в контроллере этого действия мне пришлось изменить.
Контроллер

```
public function form(Request $request)
        {
        $path = $request->file('image')->store('products');
        $params = $request->only(['name','price','des','category_id','image']);
        $params['image'] = $path;
        Products::create($params);
        }
```

Код модели Products

```
class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
    public function categorys()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Все поля добавьте в $fillable